# Forming new equation from the sums and products of roots of quartic equation

Tags: systems-of-equations, self-learning, products

Let $$b^2h^2m^4-2b^2hkm^3+ (a^2h^2+b^2k^2-a^4e^4)m^2-2a^2hkm+a^2k^2=0$$ with $e^4=\left(-\frac{b^2-a^2}{a^2}\right)^2$

Let $m_1,m_2,m_3,m_4$ be the four solutions. Let $m_1,m_2$ be the slopes of mutually perpendicular normals to the ellipse. So the sums and products of roots of this quartic equations are as follows:-

$$\begin{align}
m_1+m_2+m_3+m_4&=\frac{2k}{h}\\
m_1m_2+m_1m_3+m_1m_4+m_2m_3+m_2m_4+m_3m_4&=\frac{a^2h^2+b^2k^2-a^4e^4}{b^2h^2}\\
m_1m_2m_3+m_1m_2m_4+m_1m_3m_4+m_2m_3m_4&=\frac{2a^2k}{b^2h}\\
m_1m_2m_3m_4&=\frac{a^2k^2}{b^2h^2}\end{align}$$

and $$m_1m_2=-1$$

Now how to eliminate $m_1,m_2,m_3,m_4$ from these five equations, so that we get the equation in terms of $a,b,h,k$?

How to derive $(a^2+b^2)(h^2+k^2)(a^2k^2+b^2h^2)^2=(a^2-b^2)^2(a^2k^2-b^2h^2)^2\tag{1}$ from these above five equations?

Now, I got another equations also after doing some algebra.

$(b^2h^2-a^2k^2)m_1^2-(2a^2k+2b^2k)m_1+a^2k^2-b^2h^2=0 \tag{2}$

The roots of equation(3) are [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28b%5E2*h%5E2-a%5E2k%5E2%29m%5E2-%282a%5E2*k%2B2*b%5E2*k%29*m%2Ba%5E2*k%5E2-b%5E2*h%5E2%3D0%2C%20solve%20for%20m)

$m_2=-\frac{1}{m_1},m_3=\frac{a*k}{b*h},m_4=-\frac{a*k}{b*h}$

But these roots are not satifying the following equation.
$$m_1m_2m_3+m_1m_2m_4+m_1m_3m_4+m_2m_3m_4=\frac{2a^2k}{b^2h}$$

The above equation can be written as $$-(m_3+m_4)-\frac{2a^2k^2}{b^2h^2}*(m_1+m_2)=\frac{2a^2k}{b^2h^2}\tag{3}$$

Since $m_3+m_4=0, m_1+m_2=\frac{2k}{h}$

Equation (3) becomes $-\frac{2a^2k^3}{b^2h^3}=\frac{2a^2k}{b^2h}$

Does it mean$-h=k$ and/or vice versa? Would any member explain me this discrepancy?

I also got $(a^2-b^2)^2=(a^2+b^2)(h^2+k^2)$ which will be helpful in arriving at equation(1).

How to plot this equation in www.wolframalpha.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving this problem is possible by hand, but takes a long time.  The exact process of solving a quartic equation is outlined [here](https://www.1728.org/quartic2.htm).

Once you solve the quartic equation, you will get the values of $m_1$, $m_2$, $m_3$, and $m_4$ in terms of $a,b,h,$ and $k$.  Then, you substitute those values into these equations, giving you what you wanted.

Comment: I have not obtained the equation i mentioned in my original post, even after using your quartic equation calculator. I tried www.wolframalpha.com to get the 4 roots of this quartic equation but all of them were complex and not real roots.

Comment: If you'd like me to diagnose this further, then please post either the work from the quartic equation calculator, or else the results from Wolfram Alpha, and how you concluded that all of them are complex (which is actually possible for a quartic equation).

Comment: Roots of quartic equation are not complex but they are very lengthy. How to use at least one of them to get equation (1) stated in my original post?

Comment: @DhamnekarWinod If you look at the WolphramAlpha link you posted, the solution is that in fact $m_1=0$.  So you would substitute that value into the original equation, and you would have a much easier problem to work with.  Again, if you post more of your work in this direction, I can help you if you get stuck somewhere else.